# Getting Display modes mac os X

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes gives more number of display modes than shown in system preferences pane..i wanted only those display modes which are shown under system preferences-> displays..how do i get only those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking each mode with `CGDisplayModeIsUsableForDesktopGUI()` will allow you to filter out modes which are too low-resolution, or have too shallow of a color depth, to be used as the "desktop" resolution. That should eliminate most of the truly wacky modes.